# Making a 2D Matlab figure that contains multiple images which start at a given point (x,y)

Tags: matlab, 2d

## Problem

I am trying to make a 2D figure in Matlab which consists of multiple images and a graph with plot data (which I could eventually convert into an image too). For these images and graph, I need to be able to specify where they are located in my cartesion coordinate system.

For my specific case, it  is sufficient to be able to "tell" Matlab where the left-bottom corner of the image is.

[image]

So for the example above. I would need some "trick" to let "bird1.jpg" start at position `(a,b)`, "bird2.jpg" at position `(c,d)` and my plot at position `(e,f)` in one Matlab figure.

## Solution to problem

Thanks to chappjc I was able to find a solution for my problem. Here is the code I used such that other people can use it in the future too.

```
figure_color = [.741 .717 .42];
axe_color = [1 1 1];
Screen.fig = figure('units','pixels',...
           'name','Parallel projection',...
           'menubar','none',...
           'numbertitle','off',...
           'position',[100 100 650 720],...
           'color',figure_color,...
           'busyaction','cancel',...
           'renderer','opengl');
Screen.axes = axes('units','pix',...
         'position',[420 460 200 200],... % (420,460) is the position of the first image
         'ycolor',axe_color,...
         'xcolor',axe_color,...
         'color',axe_color,...
         'xtick',[],'ytick',[],...
         'xlim',[-.1 7.1],...
         'ylim',[-.1 7.1],...
         'visible','On');
Screen.img = imshow(phantom);
Screen.axes2 = axes('units','pix',...
         'position',[0 0 200 200],... % (0,0) is the position of the second image
         'ycolor',axe_color,...
         'xcolor',axe_color,...
         'color',axe_color,...
         'xtick',[],'ytick',[],...
         'xlim',[-.1 7.1],...
         'ylim',[-.1 7.1],...
         'visible','On');
Screen.img2 = imshow(phantom);
```

Basically what I do is first creating a (big) figure, and then create a first axe at a certain position in this big picture, and make it the default axe. In this axe I display my first image (made with the phantom function). After that I make a new axe at a another position and make it again the default axe. After I have done that, I place an image there too (the same picture, but you can also use another one if you want). You can also use handles which is the more clean method, as  chappjc describes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Positioning axes in a figure

One approach would be to manipulate the `Position` property of multiple axes in a figure.  To make multiple axes in a figure:

```
hf = figure;
ha0 = axes('parent',hf,'Position',[x0 y0 w0 h0]);
ha1 = axes('parent',hf,'Position',[x1 y1 w1 h1]);
```

Then display your images and plots into the axes by specifying the handle (i.e. ha0 or ha1).  For example: `image(img0,'Parent',ha0)` or `imshow(img1,'parent',ha1)`.

### Single Large Image

Another approach is to make a single large image and simply display it with `image`/`imshow`/etc.

First for the plots, you can use `getframe` followed by `frame2im` to get an image in a matrix format.

Next, decide what goes into your combined image and compute the largest box required to circumscribe the images (using their origins and sizes find the largest x and y coordinate), which includes the origin presumably.  Use this info to make a blank image (e.g. `img = zeros(h,w,3)` for and RGB image).